# Usage of url_encode

Tags: urlencode

I tried using Ruby's url_encode (doc [here](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.9.3/ERB/Util%3aurl_encode).)

It encodes `http://www.google.com` as `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`. But it turns out that I cannot open the latter via a browser. If so, what's the use of this function? What is it useful for, when the URL that it encodes can't even be opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical use is the HTTP **GET** method, in where you need a query String.

Query String 1:

```
valudA=john&valueB=john2
```

Actual value server get:

- valueA : "john"
- valueB : "john2"

**url_encode** is used to make the key-value pair enable to store the string which includes some **non-ASCII encoded character** such as space and special character.

**Suppose the valueB will store my name, code 4 j, you need to encode it because there are some spaces.**

```
url_encode("code 4 j")
code%204%20j
```

Query string 2:

valueA=john&valueB=code%204%20j

Actual value server get:

- valueA: "john"
- valueB: "code 4 j"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, why can't the server store it as `code 4 j` with spaces? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks for your remind:) I have never thought about this before, What I know from google is that URL　is designed to be encoded in ASCII and there is no space in ASCII. I have also updated my answer to non-ASCII encoded character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `url_encode` to encode for example the keys/values of a GET request.

Here is an example of what a SO search query URL looks after encoding:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+.net+or+asp.net

As you can see, url encoding appears to be applied only on the last part of the URL, after the last slash.

In general you cannot use url_encode on your entire URL or you will also encode the special characters in a normal URL like the :// in your example.

You can check a tutorial that explains how it works here: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/